# Using more than one log4j appender according to web context

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss6.x

I am using JBoss 6 and deployed 2 projects on this JBoss, they have different web context. They both use hibernate and the same core package on background but I want to differentiate log files according to web contexts. Because core package is the same java package for both projects.

I have searched on the internet also in log4j manuals but couldn't find any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the log4j [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) and some coding, i.e. writing a custom appender.
Otherwise you can switch your logging framework to [logback](http://logback.qos.ch), which is the proper successor of log4j. Logback defines a particular type of **appender**, the [Sift](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/chapters/appenders/sift/SiftExample.html) which does exactly, and more, of what you're trying to achieve.